# How to simplify the conditional statement

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simplify the following conditional statement. Are there better way to do this? Thanks.

```
 if ($element.is('#resize')) {
     css.left =+ 20;
     css.top =+ 3;

     if ($('#holder .Main').length < 5 ) {
         img.css('display', 'none');
     }

     img.insertBefore($element);
     img.css(css);

 } else if($element.is('#bt_id3')) {
     css.left =+ 20;
     css.top =+ 3;

     if ($('#id .Main').length < 5 ) {
         img.css('display', 'none');
     }

     img.insertBefore($element);
     img.css(css);
 }
```

Comment: You may want to post this over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you want to simplify?

Comment: It would also help if you detailed what you were trying to do/accomplish versus just posting the code.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing different between the `if` and the `else` clauses is the selector in the internal `if`.  You could isolate that this way:

```
var eltId = false;
if ($element.is('#resize')) eltId = '#holder';
if ($element.is('#bt_id3')) eltId = '#id';
if( eltId !== false ) {
    css.left=+20;
    css.top=+3;
    if($(eltId + ' .Main').length<5){img.css('display', 'none');}
    img.insertBefore($element);
    img.css(css);
}
```

That makes it a little DRYer.

Comment: essentially voting for my answer, as both are the same (except for eltId vs actually saving the reference, and spacing :-).

Answer (score 1):

```
if($element.is('#resize') || $element.is('#bt_id3')){
    var elem = $element.is('#resize') ? $('#holder .Main') : $('#id .Main');
    css.left=+20;
    css.top=+3;
    if(elem.length<5){img.hide();} // USE HERE THE 'elem' VARIABLE and '.hide()'
    img.insertBefore($element);
    img.css(css);
}
```

Comment: css top and left only get applied if the element is one or the other - but element may not be of either type!

Comment: One problem, Roko -- this code will execute if `element` isn't `#resize` or `#id`, which is not equivalent to the original code.  Otherwise it's very pretty.

Answer (score 1):

This does not change any workings, but it is still not too pretty. Lots of magic numbers and lack of comments and context make for weird code...

```
var e = false;
if ($element.is('#resize')) e = $('#holder .Main');
else if ($element.is('#bt_id3')) e = $('#id .Main');

if (e) {
      css.left=+20;
      css.top=+3;
      if (e.length<5) {
          img.css('display', 'none');
      }
      img.insertBefore($element);
      img.css(css);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
$element.is("#resize") ? (css.left = 20, css.top = 3, 5 > $("#holder .Main")
.length && img.css("display", "none"), img.insertBefore($element), img.css(css)) : $element.is("#bt_id3") && (css.left = 20, css.top = 3, 5 > $("#id .Main")
.length && img.css("display", "none"), img.insertBefore($element), img.css(css))
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick re-factor yields:

```
css.left = +20;
css.top = +3;

if ($element.is('#resize')) {
    if ($('#holder .Main').length < 5) {
        img.css('display', 'none');
    }
} else if ($element.is('#bt_id3')) {
    if ($('#id .Main').length < 5) {
        img.css('display', 'none');
    }
}

img.insertBefore($element);
img.css(css);
```

Comment: Same problem as Roko's answer.